# How do I render a Twig template and load a CSS file from a controller?

Tags: 8, theming

Is this considered a good practice for rendering a Twig template and loading a CSS file from a controller?

#### DefaultController.php

```
namespace Drupal\acme\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment;

class DefaultController extends ControllerBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface 
{
  /**
  * @var Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment
  */
  protected $twig;

  public function __construct(TwigEnvironment $twig)
  {
    $this->twig = $twig;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container)
  {
    return new static(
      $container->get('twig')
    );
  }

  /**
   * hello
   * @param  string $name
   * @return string
   */
  public function hello($name) 
  {

    $template = $this->twig->loadTemplate(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'acme') . '/templates/hello.html.twig'
    );

    $markup = [
      '#markup' => $template->render([ 'name' => $name ]),
      '#attached' => [ 'css' => [
          drupal_get_path('module', 'acme') . '/assets/css/acme.css'
        ]
      ]
    ];

    return drupal_render($markup);
  }
}
```

#### acme.routing.yml

```
acme_hello:
  path: '/acme/hello/{name}'
  defaults:
    _content: '\Drupal\acme\Controller\DefaultController::hello'
    _title: 'acme Title'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

#### hello.html.twig

```
<div class="acme-hello-text">
  <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! About what are you concerned? Also, "a good example" is rather subjective; you should explain what is a good example for you.

Comment: I was asking if this is considered a good practice, is any way I can edit the question ?

Comment: Why would you want to call twig manually? You should define your template with hook_theme(), just like you did in 7.x and then use #theme, just like in Drupal 7, you don't need to bother about using twig directly.

Comment: Btw. You should use `\Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot()` instead of deprecated `drupal_render()`.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand, the controller should just contain the following code.

```
class DefaultController implements ControllerInterface {
  public function hello($name) {
    $twig = $this->container->get('twig');
    $path = $this->templateDir . 'hello.html.twig';
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate($path);

    return [
      '#markup' => $template->render(['name' => $name]),
    ];
  }
}
```

See also [Drupal 8: An Introduction to the New Production](http://www.titancloudworks.com/captains_log/post/drupal-an-introduction-to-the-new-production).

I still have to find a reason to do this, thought. [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/8) is still supported by Drupal 8, and it doesn't seem it is getting deprecated, at this time. The only difference is that in Drupal 8, `theme()` has been renamed [`_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/_theme/8); as such, it should not be called directly.
Since you are asking if your code is considered good practice, I would say no: You should do as you did with Drupal 7, defining a theme function in `hook_theme()` that uses a template. Then return markup similar to the following one in your controller method.

```
[
  '#theme' => $your_theme_function,
  '#name' => $name,
];
```

Replace `$your_theme_function` with the theme function ID, and `#name` with the array index used for `'variables'`.
Actually, there is a difference between Drupal 7 and Drupal 8: While Drupal 7 allows you to attach JavaScript and CSS, Drupal 8 allows you to attach just libraries, which are a set of JavaScript and CSS files with dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I refactored my code as follow, removing code from the controller class and updating the method hello

**DefaultController.php**

```
namespace Drupal\acme\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class DefaultController extends ControllerBase 
{

  /**
   * hello
   * @param  string $name
   * @return string
   */
    public function hello($name) 
  {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'hello_page',
      '#name' => $name,
      '#attached' => [ 
        'css' => [
          drupal_get_path('module', 'acme') . '/assets/css/acme.css'
        ]
      ]
    ];
  }
}
```

And also adding a new function to

**acme.module**

```
  function acme_theme() {
    $theme['hello_page'] = [
      'variables' => ['name' => NULL],
      'template' => 'hello'
    ];

    return $theme;
  }
```

If interested you can see a gist containing all of the files and code here https://gist.github.com/jmolivas/d29065493a91f16f35b2