# Is there a way to retrieve DRUPAL TWIG template's with core drupal 8 javascript functions like twig.js?

Tags: theming, javascript, 8

Is there a way to get precompiled twig templates from drupal 8?

Example :

Drupal.getTemplate('my-template.twig')(data);

Comment: Your title and question differ to me. The title sounds like it's about generating markup, whereas the question is about retrieving the template information.

Comment: I have rephrased my question title.

Comment: See kiamlaluno's answer [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112340/how-do-i-render-a-twig-template-and-load-a-css-file-from-a-controller)

Comment: Ok, now the title and question seems to agree, but I don't understand what the question is. Which doesn't have to mean there's anything wrong with it, as I'm not very knowledgeable on the topic. Just saying you may want to consider clarifying what you are after.

Comment: Something like https://github.com/adamdicarlo/grunt-twig

But with drupal