# How can I convert Twig to HTML?

Tags: 8, theming

I created a module to generate and display demo content; I would like to know if I can use Twig inside my pricing-table.html file and use a function to convert all data to HTML to use for `#markup`.

How does Drupal 8 convert Twig in HTML?

```
  public function princingTablesPage() {
    return array(
      '#title' => 'Pricing Tables',
      '#markup' => file_get_contents(__DIR__."/../../demo_pages/pricing-table.html")
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at kiamlaluno's answer [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112340/how-do-i-render-a-twig-template-and-load-a-css-file-from-a-controller?rq=1), is that what you're looking for?